# Debian GNU/Linux on a HP Proliant ML 370 G4

Tags: debian-lenny, hp-proliant

I'm going to setup last Debian on a HP Proliant ML 370 G4.

Do you know if Debian minimal netinstall will work ? 
Should i prepare any specific drivers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://wiki.debian.org/HP/ProLiant#Needbnx2firmware